# Асинхронный метод подключения к базе данных - c#

Tags: c#, sql, методы, асинхронность, инициализация

У меня есть метод:

```
public static void Connection()
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                string[] allFoundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filename, "Database.mdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string file in allFoundFiles)
                {
                    dataSource = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + file + ";Integrated Security=True";
                }

                connect = new SqlConnection(dataSource);
                connect.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!");
            }
        }
```

В этом методе выполняется поиск файла базы данных, а в дальнейшем его подключение. Как мне сделать этот метод асинхронным, чтобы он срабатывал на фоне, при открытии приложения?

Comment: Подождите с асинхронностью. Сделайте сначала, чтобы это работало без нее. Что здесь происходит, если `enabled` равно `false`?

Comment: Метод работает, подключение выполняется, enabled нужен при вызове, если я установлю true, то он откроет базу данных, если false, то закроет.

Comment: Нет, не закроет.

Comment: Почему не закроет?

Comment: Потому что Вы каждый раз создаете новый объект соединения. А старый (открытый) куда девается?

Comment: Хорошо, я могу заменить:
if (enabled == true)
                {
                    connect.Open();
                } else
                {
                    connect.Close();
                }
На connect.Open();
Но как мне закрыть подключение потом?

Comment: `if (connect != null) { connect.Close(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static async Task Connection()
{
  ...
  await connect.OpenAsync();
}
```